# grpcurl to send a message of type 'Any'

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java, proto3, grpcurl

How to send a message of type 'Any' using grpcurl?

I have this proto:

```
message MyRequest {
  string request_id = 1;
  repeated google.protobuf.Any payload = 2;
}
```

I am sending this request:

```
{
   "request_id":"1",
   "payload":[
      {
         "@type":"type.googleapis.com/com.my.type.Payload",
         "id":"12345",
         "message": "Hello",
      }
   ]
}
```

grpcurl -plaintext -d '{"request_id": "1", "payload": [{"@type": "type.googleapis.com/com.my.type.Payload", "id": "12345", "message": "Hello"}]}' localhost:1000 com.my.service.ServiceName/Method

but I get an error: `Error invoking method "com.my.service.ServiceName/Method": error getting request data: unknown message type "com.my.type.Payload"`

The server is a Spring Boot project in Kotlin, so I added a bean

```
@Bean
fun protobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter(): ProtobufHttpMessageConverter? {
    val typeRegistry: JsonFormat.TypeRegistry = JsonFormat.TypeRegistry.newBuilder()
        .add(com.my.type.Payload.getDescriptor())
        .build()

    val printer = JsonFormat.printer().usingTypeRegistry(typeRegistry)
    return ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter(JsonFormat.parser(), printer)
}
```

But it didn't help. How to fix it?

Comment: I suspect -- but don't know -- that you need to encode `payload` as a `[]byte` rather than treat is as an encapsulated message. Unfortunately, I don't know how you'd encode it but you may be able to get away with base64.

Comment: It may be worth submitting an issue to the `gRPCurl` repo and asking there: https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl/issues

Comment: Thank you, found the same issue there: https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl/issues/193

Comment: You're welcome. I tried searching for issues there for you and did not find that one!